# How to get email id as a part of google oauth 2.0 googl drive sign in

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-auth-library

I am creating a website where in one page Google drive sign in is required.  I am using Google's OAuth 2.0. I have used the below scopes

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

When I tried printing the info, email is showing as null. I don't want the email to be null. It needs to have the signed in Google drive email
How do I get it ?

I tried using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

But even then the email is not shown

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
  REDIRECT_URL
);

const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
];

const authorizationUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: scopes,
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]  where are you trying to print it from and where is it null?

Comment: where exactly in that code are you printing the users email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to arrive at a solution by making an axios GET call to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo and passing the access token as bearer token

Answer (score 1):

im using the oauth2Client in nodejs

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library')
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(googleId, googleSecret, 'postmessage')

const {tokens} = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code) // exchange

//get email
const ticket = await oAuth2Client.verifyIdToken({
idToken: tokens?.id_token,
audience: googleId
})
const payload = ticket.getPayload()
const userid = payload['sub']
const email = payload['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean by email id of a user.  However the [about.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get) method returns some basic information about a user. In the event that you are actually looking for the users email address. Then the about.get does return that.  There is also permission id which may or may not be the users id on google itself I have never actually bothered to double check that.

```
// npm install googleapis@105 @google-cloud/local-auth@2.1.0 --save
// npm install googleapis


const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

// Token File Name
const TOKEN_FILE = 'quickstart_about_email.json'

// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), TOKEN_FILE);
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'C:\\Development\\FreeLance\\GoogleSamples\\Credentials\\CredWebEverything.json';

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
    try {
        const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
        const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
        return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
    } catch (err) {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file comptible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
    const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
    const keys = JSON.parse(content);
    const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        type: 'authorized_user',
        client_id: key.client_id,
        client_secret: key.client_secret,
        refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
    });
    await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
    let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (client) {
        return client;
    }
    client = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPES,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    });
    if (client.credentials) {
        await saveCredentials(client);
    }
    return client;
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 * @param {OAuth2Client} authClient An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function getUserEmail(authClient) {
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: authClient});
    const res = await drive.about.get({
        pageSize: 10,
        fields: 'user(emailAddress)',
    });    

    // print users email
    console.log(`Email: ${res.data.user.emailAddress}`);

}

authorize().then(getUserEmail).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same scenario where I was using Google Drive API and doing the Auth stuff afterward. I needed to get the email of the user used in the authentication screen. But the redirect URI doesn't come with any user data.
Here's what I did.

It is mostly similar to @JeffKGabriel's answer but I did a little bit differently.

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  CLIENT_ID.value(), // used the same client ID used for generating the URL
  CLIENT_SECRET.value(), // used the same client secret used for generating the URL
  'http://localhost:3001/somewhere', // I'm not certain but I think this could be anything that matches your defined URLs
);
const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(authCode);
const { email } = await oauth2Client.getTokenInfo(tokens.access_token);
console.log(`email: ${email}`);
```

I have struggled so much with this so I hope someone will find this and not waste time like I did :)